# binary search tree overloading == operator or just need general advice

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am working on a program that reads in a text file that the user inputs, creates a text file that the user inputs, names the text file that the user wants, and then sorts the text file sorting words above the user entered in threshold and displays the words and how many times it was found to the output file the user specify's. I have most of the code finished but I'm getting a compiler error heres the sample output, error and code

sample output

```
Enter name of input command file; press return.
history.in
Enter name of output file; press return.
history.out
Enter name of test run; press return.
sample
Enter the minimum size word to be considered.
5
Sample results (found in user specified output file):
sample
abacus 4
abstract 1
adding 1
addition 2
advances 1
after 3
```

where the word is the word found in the text file, and the number next to it is how many times it was found.

error code

```
C:\Users\kevin jack\Desktop\prog-4>g++ -o try main.cpp
main.cpp: In function `void Process(TreeNode*&, StrType)':
main.cpp:49: error: no match for 'operator==' in 'tree->TreeNode::info.WordType:
:word == s'
main.cpp:51: error: no match for 'operator<' in 's < tree->TreeNode::info.WordTy
pe::word'
```

main.cpp

```
//main.cpp
#include <fstream>
#include "StrType.h"
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct WordType
{
       public:
              StrType word;       
              int count;
};

struct TreeNode
{
       WordType info;
       TreeNode* left;
       TreeNode* right;
};

class ListType
{
      public:
             ListType();
             void InsertOrIncrement (StrType string);
             void Print(std::ofstream&) const;
      private:
              TreeNode* root;
};


ListType::ListType()
{
     root=NULL;
}

void Process(TreeNode*& tree, StrType s)
{
     if(tree == NULL)
     {
         tree = new TreeNode;
         tree->info.word = s;
         tree->info.count = 1;
         tree->left = NULL;
         tree->right = NULL;
     }
     else if (tree->info.word == s)
         tree->info.count++;
     else if (s < tree->info.word)
         Process(tree->left, s);
     else 
         Process(tree->right, s);
}

void ListType::InsertOrIncrement(StrType s)
{
     Process(root, s);
}

void Print (TreeNode* tree, std::ofstream& outFile)
 {
      if (tree!= NULL)
      {
          Print(tree->left, outFile);
          tree->info.word.PrintToFile(true, outFile);
          outFile <<" "<< tree->info.count;
          Print(tree->right, outFile);
      }
 }

 void ListType::Print(std::ofstream& outFile) const
 {
      ::Print(root, outFile);
 }


int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    ListType list;
    string inFileName;
    string outFileName;
    string outputLabel;
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;
    StrType string;
    int minimumLenght;

    cout<<"enter in imput file name."<<endl;
    cin>>inFileName;
    inFile.open(inFileName.c_str());

    cout<<"enter name of output file."<<endl;
    cin>>outFileName;
    outFile.open(outFileName.c_str());

    cout<<"enter name of test run."<<endl;
    cin>>outputLabel;
    outFile<< outputLabel << endl;

    cout<<"enter the min word size."<<endl;
    cin>>minimumLenght;

    string.GetStringFile(true, ALPHA_NUM, inFile);
    while(inFile)
    {
         if(string.LenghtIs() >= minimumLenght)
            list.InsertOrIncrement(string);
         string.GetStringFile(true, ALPHA_NUM, inFile);
    }

    list.Print(outFile);
    outFile.close();
    inFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

StrType.h

```
//StrType.h
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

const int MAX_CHARS=100;
enum InType{ALPHA_NUM, ALPHA, NON_WHITE, NOT_NEW};

class StrType
{
      public:
             void MakeEmpty();
            void GetString(bool skip, InType charsAllowed);
             void GetStringFile(bool skip, InType charsAllowed,
                std::ifstream& inFile);
             void PrintToScreen(bool newLine);
             void PrintToFile(bool newLine, std::ofstream& outFile);
             int LenghtIs();
             void CopyString(StrType& newString);
      private:
              char letters[MAX_CHARS + 1];
};

void StrType::MakeEmpty()
{
     letters[0] ='\0';
}
```

i think this about overloading the == operator but im not very good at overloading. if someone could help me out anyway possible that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You are not to **overload** but to **define** `operator==` and `operator<` for your `class StrType`
You can do it as follows:

```
class StrType  
{   
public:   
    ...  
    bool operator==(const StrType& other) const;  
    bool operator<(const StrType& other) const; 
    ...   
};  

bool StrType::operator==(const StrType& other) const  
{  
    return (strcmp(letters, other.letters) == 0);  
}  

bool StrType::operator<(const StrType& other) const  
{  
    return (strcmp(letters, other.letters) < 0);  
}
```

Comment: The operators as you define them are not correct. When defining as members, you only have `bool operator== (struct WordType &other)`. And comparison should probably be `const` and take a `const` argument.

Comment: ok so should i so should i use both the global and structure methods and if so where does the global one go?

Comment: @user1061266, you should use only one of these methods. As for me, I prefer member functions

Comment: ok and what does the implementation do? sorry my teacher flew over this stuff

Comment: @user1061266, in implementation you describe the way you compare objects of the class. In your case, you should compare private char arrays

Comment: ok so the bools should go in the struct WordType and the implementation is in the class StrType?

Comment: No, your `WordType` is correct, you should check out `class StrType`. Also, you compare objects of your class by its private members, so you **must** make operators as public member functions

Comment: Place it in `StrType.cpp` (or at least in `StrType.h` if you don't have a cpp-file and don't want to create it)

Comment: ok thank you for clearing that up. also, where does this code go?


    bool StrType::operator==(const StrType& other) const  
    {  
        return (strcmp(letters, other.letters) == 0);  
    }

because when i try to compile i get this really big error

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement "operator ==" and "operator <" for struct WordType.

They can be member functions like this:

```
struct WordType
{
    bool operator == (const WordType &other)
    {
        // implementation
    }

    bool operator < (const WordType &other)
    {
        // implementation
    }
};
```

Or global functions like this:

```
bool operator == (const WordType &left, const WordType &right)
{
    // implementation
}

bool operator < (const WordType &left, const WordType &right)
{
    // implementation
}
```

Comment: Did you read the comments for the other answer (which sounds exactly the same)?  In case you go for the member-operator, you should declare them `const` for maximum usability.

Comment: ok thank you for clearing that up. also where would the 


    bool StrType::operator==(const StrType& other) const  
    {  
        return (strcmp(letters, other.letters) == 0);  
    }

because when i try to compile i get a really big error